# Vector Autoregression Historical Decomposition

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, variance-decomposition

I would  like to perform a historical decomposition of my VAR model that is identified with timing restrictions, similar to that in figure 10 of this paper:

http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/aer.103.4.1507

How, in the simplest possible terms, would one calculate the contribution of a shock to a given dependent variable?